# Can not deserialize value of type java.util.Date from String "Aug 29, 2023 5:48:51 PM": expected format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"

Tags: java, json, datetime, serialization, date-format

I am trying to parse this data "Aug 29, 2023 5:48:51 PM" which is in String format to JSON but getting the below error

*Can not deserialize value of type java.util.Date from String "Aug 29, 2023 5:48:51 PM": expected format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"*

The POJO declaration of the corresponding field is given below:

```
@JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS")
    @Column(name = "createdOn")
    private Date createdOn;
```

Pls help

I have tried to modify the pojo declaration of the field to this

```
@JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS")
@Column(name = "createdOn")
private Date createdOn;
```

Comment: Tip: Educate the publisher of your data about using only standard ISO 8601 formats for date-time values.

Comment: You should not use `Date`. That class was always poorly designed and exactly for that reason was supplanted by [java.time, the modern Java datre and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html) a decade ago. Perhaps `LocalDateTme` is the right type for your use case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### java.time

The `java.util` date-time API and their corresponding parsing/formatting type, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. In March 2014, the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html) supplanted the legacy date-time API. Since then, it has been strongly recommended to switch to `java.time`, the modern date-time API.

The format corresponding to your date-time string is `MMM dd, uuuu h:m:s a` in the `en_US` locale.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTimeFormatter parser = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM dd, uuuu h:m:s a", new Locale("en_US"));
        System.out.println(LocalDateTime.parse("Aug 29, 2023 5:48:51 PM", parser));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2023-08-29T17:48:51
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/gb9QfT)

Based on this description, you can make the following changes in your code:

```
@JsonFormat(pattern = "MMM dd, uuuu h:m:s a", shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, locale = "en_US")
@Column(name = "createdOn")
private LocalDateTime createdOn;
```

Learn about the modern date-time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**